# Spring REST by GET error 500 при несуществующем id?

Tags: java, spring, rest

Суть такова: при вызове по GET с id, которого нет в бд, падает с ошибкой 500, вместо сообщения моей кастомной ошибки. Не могу понять почему и как исправить. Спасибо!

Контроллер:

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException;
import ru.petClinic.common.ResponseDto;
import ru.petClinic.errors.ValidateException;

import java.util.List;

@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("doctor")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DoctorController {

    private final DoctorService doctorService;

    @GetMapping("{id}")
    ResponseDto<DoctorResponseDto> getById(@PathVariable Long id) throws ValidateException {
        log.debug("getById: started with id: {}", id);
        DoctorResponseDto result = doctorService.getById(id);
        log.info("getById: finished for id: {}, with result: {}", id, result);
        return new ResponseDto<>(null, result);
    }
```

Service:

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import ru.petClinic.errors.ValidateException;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DoctorService {

    private final DoctorRepository doctorRepository;
    private final DoctorMapper doctorMapper;

    public DoctorResponseDto getById(Long id) throws ValidateException {
        Doctor doctorEntity = doctorRepository.getById(id).orElseThrow(()
                -> new ValidateException(String.format("Врача с таким id: %s не найдено.", id)));
        return doctorMapper.fromEntity(doctorEntity);
    }
```

ResponseDto:

```
import lombok.Value;
@Value
public class ResponseDto<T> {
        String error;
    T data;
}
```

MyException:

```
public class ValidateException extends Exception {
    public ValidateException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: а почему у полей `doctorService`, `doctorRepository` и `doctorMapper` нет аннотации `@Autowired`? они же будут null c вылетом не вашего исключения, а соответствующего runtime-системного :) И модификатор final вроде как излишен.

Comment: Вы не правы). Все работает отлично с аннотацией RequiredArgsConstructor, ну или классическим конструктором с применением private final, ибо "In the newest Spring release, it's constructor does not need to be annotated with Autowired annotation."

Comment: Где у вас код, который как-то брошенное исключение превратит в html с красивой ошибкой или хотя бы в текст stracktrace в браузере? Сейчас все работает правильно - необработанное исключение это 500 ошибка.

Comment: Точно, ExceptionHandler добавлю на перехват ошибки. Я думал над этим, но почему-то не сделал. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сейчас все работает правильно - необработанное исключение это 500 ошибка. Чтобы исправить нужно добавить метод(ы) в контроллер или в отдельный бин (удобно для централизованной обработка ошибок):

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> handleException(Exception e) {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(e.getMessage(),  mapExceptionToStatus(exception.getClass()));
}

@ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> handleIOException(IOException ex) {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```